# How to identify binaries are for Armv7 or Armv8

Tags: assembly, arm, reverse-engineering

Is there any way looking at the binaries and identifying its built for Armv7 or built for Armv8

Best Regards
Oz.

Comment: If you mean AArch64, then obviously the metadata will indicate that.  But if you just mean 32-bit mode but using some new instructions that ARMv8 introduced, disassemble and look for new instructions.  (like `ldar` / `stlr` acquire / sequential-release load and store instructions, or ldaexd for a 64-bit atomic acquire-load.) https://developer.arm.com/docs/den0024/latest/an-introduction-to-the-armv8-instruction-sets/the-armv8-instruction-sets

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @fuz There are two different patch for two different solution ARMv7 and ARMv8 . and i want to automate the situation if i can check binaries maybe for the assembly op codes without using any tool i would just apply correct patch for the correct binary.

Comment: @OzgurOz What format are the binaries in?  There is no 100% sure way to differentiate AArch32 machine code from AArch64 machine code and heuristical methods are slightly annoying to program.  Checking metdata is probably the easiest way.

Comment: In general no.  not possible.  disassembly is not reliable on armv7 because of the likelyhood of thumb mode.  but if you know the entry point in the binary you could try to disassemble the first few instructions maybe handfuls (in execution order) and see if they make sense for either architecture since they are completely incompatible isas.  If one makes sense the other looks bad or jumps off into la la land, then you might assume one vs the other.   assuming you have the right entry point.